# Class not registered error using Innovative Gateway Payment C# test project

Tags: c#

1. You'll need to download the project from this link first, it will only take a second.

http://www.innovativegateway.com/d_reference.aspx

1. Download the Windows .NET 3.5 Client
2. Unzip it and open up the C# project file
3. Run the project
4. Put in a test credit card number and any first and last name.  Here is a test visa card you can use: 4012888888881881  (testing only it's not a real card)

When you run the application it gives the error:

"class not registered"

I tried registering ugpiclient.dll (using regsvr32) and it still gives the same error.  I tried setting up a reference to ugpiclient.dll and I still get the same error. I tried setting up a reference to Interop.UpgiClient.dll and I still get the same error.

Can anyone just get that error to not show up so I can use the code?

Comment: I would contact their support.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. When you download their project, visual studio 2012 upgrades the project.

1. Right click your project and click properties.
2. Click Build
3. Set the target platform to x86

That solved the problem while registering the upgiclient.dll in the syswo64 directory (using regsvr32).